# How can I round off value in dynamic col-md-(value) in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, ceil

Hi I have some fields which are coming dynamic and I am adjusting the `col-md-` according to number of fields. So I wrote an expression some thing like this `<div class="col-md-{{12 / variants.length}}` Now I want to round off the value. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller maybe try rounding there instead of on the HTML side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function defined in the controller, e.g.

```
<div class="col-md-{{colWidth(variants.length)}}">something</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.colWidth = function(nbVariants) {
   // Use whatever formula suits your needs. Be aware that this may return 0
   return Math.round(12/nbVariants);    
}
```